# Could not find a part of the path 'c:\users\dell\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\CreateCon\CreateCon\Content\Images\1.png'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index1(HttpPostedFileBase doc)
        {
            var path = "";
            if(doc != null)
            {
                if(doc.ContentLength>0)
                {
                    //check image type or not
                    if (Path.GetExtension(doc.FileName).ToLower() ==".jpg"
                       || Path.GetExtension(doc.FileName).ToLower() == ".png"
                             ||Path.GetExtension(doc.FileName).ToLower() == ".jpeg")
                    {
                        path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Content/Images"), doc.FileName);
                        doc.SaveAs(path);
                        ViewBag.UploadSeccess = true; 
                    }
                }
            }
            return View();
        }

Answer (score 1):

change this part of code

```
 path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Content/Images"), doc.FileName);
```

to:

```
 path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), doc.FileName);
```